# MKTileOverlay not defined

Tags: ios, xcode, openstreetmap, mktileoverlay

I have a simple map application using openStreetMap that works well on all iPhone simulators ( xcode 6.1, IOS 7.1 & 8.1 ). However, when I compile on a real device (iPhone 4 iOS 7.1), I encounter some issues (see screenshot), the application doesn't recognize some classes, such as MKTileOverlay, MKOverlayRender, etc.

[image: http://dealweb.fr/p.png]

The  weirdest thing is that it worked a few weeks ago, then, after I worked on another project, when I come back to this one, the problem appeared.

Maybe the problem is coming from Xcode or the device's configuration?
I searched for several days, without success, so could someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: You could post images here on SO, people don't like clicking on external links. Also, please try to post your code here. People won't be able to guess what you're working on if you don't show your code. Even a fragment of it would be helpful enough.

Comment: Delete your existing framework files from your project and add them again in project and then check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I couldn't post a screenshot, I hadn't enought point from you guys ^^! I did delete the framework a lot of times, but this don't seem to work, I also try to unistall xcode & re-install it, & the bug was fix.

I hope this won't happend to you that was horrible.

Thanks for your answer guys !